# use npm module as normal package in meteor

Tags: node.js, meteor, meteorite

**UPDATE**:

I'm using atmosphere npm package to work with node modules

I'm using this package to connect with github-api

https://github.com/mikedeboer/node-github

This package doesn't have method to get statistics of a user

There is a one pull request, In which he implemented that method

https://github.com/mikedeboer/node-github/pull/131

I made those changes in `/packages/npm/.npm/package/github` and restarted the server and error showing that

```
object has no method getStatsContributors
```

You can see the code I've added in that pull request

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This question could be improved by posting code or command snippets of what you are trying to do together with the exact error messages received.

Comment: I have no idea, but maybe someone else does.

Comment: Someone else may come along, and bug you to dig the relevant code out of the links because links go bad and all questions are supposed to be completely viewable by future viewers.

Answer (score 0):

you should add npm package to your meteor app

```
mrt add npm
```

And after that look at that : [Meteor.require](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-npm#meteorrequirenpmmodulename)

Comment: I've added that method,before the modifications the package is working fine, after the modifications too it is working fine, but it is not reading the methods that i've added to that package